# cocos2d: LabelAtlas text alignment?

Tags: iphone, text, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way in cocos2d 0.7.1 to specify the text alignment in a LabelAtlas?

I'm using a LabelAtlas for a score (displayed in the upper right corner) but when the score goes above 10, the second digit is cut off.

I can implement code to detect that and move the LabelAtlas, but is there a way to have cocos2d do it for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that works, you'll have the same problem if the score goes above 1000.

You can use the `anchorPosition` property to change where the position is defined.  For example; in my game I place the `scoreLabel` in the lower right hand corner of the screen.  To ensure it is always visible I set `anchorPosition` to be the lower right hand corner of the label and then set its `position` where I want the lower right hand corner of the label to be.

```
[scoreLabel setAnchorPoint:ccp(1, 0)];
[scoreLabel setPosition:ccp(480, 0)];
```

If you want it positioned in the upper right hand corner of the screen then you can similarly use the following code to define the anchor as the upper right corner.

```
[scoreLabel setAnchorPoint:ccp(1, 1)];
[scoreLabel setPosition:ccp(480, 320)];
```

Comment: Oh, right! Since then, I have used setAnchorPoint in another project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I simply use this to center my `LabelAtlas`:

```
[scoreLabel setAnchorPoint:ccp(.5, .5)];
```

When the score changes, the label stays center aligned without updating the position.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I did end up writing code to do this.

```
    if(delegate.score > 99) {
        [scoreLabel setPosition:ccp(374, 265)];
    } else if(delegate.score > 9) {
        [scoreLabel setPosition:ccp(410, 265)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:labels#alignment