# Cocos2d score label goes off screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my game the score will rise every time you collect a treat, I have positioned the label at the bottom left. The problem is when the score goes up part of the label goes off screen. Any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787054/cocos2d-labelatlas-text-alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the alignment to `alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft` like so:

```
        CCLabelTTF *score = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"yeahh" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 100) alignment:CCTextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:22];
```